# Plot the max function with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot the max function, but python's default max function can't take arrays, and I guess that's what matplotlib does under the hood.

So what is the correct syntax?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pylab as pylab

t = pylab.arange(-6, 6)
s = max(0,t)
plt.plot(t, s)
plt.show()

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: are you trying to plot `t` and the max value of `t`?

Comment: That's not what the error is... Please give the *actual* code.

Comment: @Veedrac woops sorry! I pasted the wrong code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.max` takes the maximum value of an array (or along a specific axis). What you want is `np.maximum`, that takes the greater value of two options:

```
In [3]: np.maximum(0, [-1,2,3])
Out[3]: array([0, 2, 3])
```

On the other hand, your error does not correspond to the code posted. `np.max(0, t)` raises a `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars` because the second argument is the axis, and a scalar number has no dimensions.